# Software Center window is blank

Tags: software-center

I can't launch the Software Center anymore. I've got a blank window each time I try to open it.

I have tried to repair it by typing "software-center" in Synaptic Package Manager, and I selected it for reinstall, but it still doesn't work.
I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Running `sudo apt-get update` didn't fix the problem

Here is the output I get when I run `software-center`

```
2012-06-21 17:15:58,122 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
```

Comment: Try to start `software-center` from terminal. Update question with the output.

Comment: If the advice in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78561/software-center-has-a-blank-window/78679#78679) doesn't help, have you tried the [Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)? (Do steps 1-4, then post the text from the terminal on [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post a link to it here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/772549) there are two workarounds.

1. `killall software-center` or
2. Reboot your system.

If this is permanent, you can check its log file: ~/.cache/software-center/software-center.log

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same bug before, and I solved it by removing the Ubuntu Software Center (`sudo apt-get remove software-center`) and installing it again (`sudo apt-get install software-center`)

Comment: Reinstalling didn't work for me unfortunately.